# Ruby: What does class << self do?

Tags: ruby

```
class Person
  class << self
    def species
      "Homo Sapien"
    end
  end
end
```

Why do i need to use class << self ?

What's the benefit ?
Why do i need it?

Comment: Please stop asking duplicates of existing questions within Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Any method declared inside `class << self` will be defined on the class instance, not instances of the class. In the example above, you'll be able to call `Person.species` but not `Person.new.species`.

Comment: @newcomer, yes, like static methods in PHP/Java.

Comment: You can also write `def self.species`, as `self` refers to the class instance within the definition of a class.

Comment: You can also write `def Person.species`, ruby gives you lots of options as you can see. Personally, I prefer using `def self.species` as it is clear that `species` is a class method without having to scroll around, *unless* **all** the methods are indeed class methods, and than I would prefer `class << self`.

Answer (score 1):

`class << obj` provides you access to metaclass (also known as eigenclass or singleton class) of `obj`, everything within that construction is executed in context of that metaclass. `self` directly in class definition references that class, so in your example, method `species` is defined as class method on `Person`.